# how to set dropdownlist to pk value just inserted?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, scope-identity

within my save function, how do I set my Dropdownlist to display the most recent PK inserted?

```
 try{
//saving stuff where pk is inserted
con.close();
DropDownListTug.Items.Clear();
DropDownListTug.DataBind();
DropDownListTug.SelectedValue = "SCOPE_IDENTITY();"; //??? 
}
```

Comment: I think you missed c# tag

Comment: Depends on the implementation of _"//saving stuff where pk is inserted
"_.

Comment: @New2This You have to assign `SelectedValue` in `Page_Load` event .However provide your code or at least explain the scenario

Comment: its a save button im clicking to insert values into the drop down list. when i click save, the item is added to the dropdownlist. however, the dropdownlist is currently reverting back to index 0 - ie the first value after i click save. i dont want that. i want it to display the index of the most recent value i just inserted.

Comment: @New2This You need to set default value or `Selectedvalue` of dropdown in `Page_Load` event. Can you show us how you are binding your dropdown at first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
  SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Tablename')
```

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx)

**NOTE**

In this scenario i think using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is more suitable as **Crud** suggested.

**UPDATE**

To update your dropdownlist you need to populate your dropdownList in `page_load` event as i told you in my comments to show recent changes and setting a default value .
Look when you click button postback occurs and your page reloads and your code binds dropdownlist again (must be in page_load event) so to set a default value for your `dropdownlist` you need to set it's `SelecedValue` in `Page_load` event.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` line of the insert query as follows.

```
// Sample sql insert statement
INSERT INTO Test(TestId,Des) 
VALUES(@testId, @des);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

And then should be executed the insert query with `ExecuteScalar()` as follows.It will return the inserted pk value.

```
 Int32 newId = (Int32) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
 DropDownListTug.SelectedValue = newId.ToString() ;
```